# Nested ifelse() statement in R not producing the desired results

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data set of boolean variables and I am trying to generate a new variable based on 3 of the existing booleans using ifelse().

The rules I'd like to implement are:

1. If any of the three columns have value 1, 1
2. If all of the three columns have value 0, 0
3. If all of the three columns have value NA, NA
4. If the three columns have some combination of 0 and NA, 0

Here is the code to generate a sample with 3 variables that I want to use to create a fourth:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0,1), 
                             var2 = c(1, NA, 0,0, 1), 
                             var3 = c(NA, NA, NA,0,1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I have tried the following to generate the new variable according to my desired rules:

```
df$newvar1 <-ifelse(df$var1 == 1 | df$var2 == 1 |df$var3 == 1, 1, 
                     ifelse((is.na(df$var1) & is.na(df$var2) & is.na(df$var3)), NA,0))
                             
df$newvar2 <- ifelse((is.na(df$var1)|df$var1==0) & 
                     (is.na(df$var2)|df$var2==0) & 
                     (is.na(df$var3)|df$var3==0),0,
                     ifelse(df$var1 == 1 | df$var2 == 1 |df$var3 == 1, 1, 
                           ifelse(is.na(df$var1) & is.na(df$var2) & is.na(df$var3), NA,NA)))
        

df$newvar3 <-ifelse(df$var1 == 1 | df$var2 == 1 |df$var3 == 1, 1, 
                     ifelse((is.na(df$var1) & is.na(df$var2) & is.na(df$var3)), NA,
                            ifelse((is.na(df$var1)|df$var1==0) & 
                              (is.na(df$var2)|df$var2==0) & 
                              (is.na(df$var3)|df$var3==0),0,0)))
```

I don't understand why newvar1 and newvar3 have NA values corresponding to combinations of NAs and 0s when both examples use "&" between the na specifications (row 3 in the results).

I am assuming that NAs don't show up in newvar2 because the first ifelse() function takes precedent.

Any insight to the ifelse() function or advice on how to get the results I'm looking for would be really helpful.

[image: Results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another possible option using `rowSums`:

```
df$newvar <- +(rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) * NA ^ (rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0) > 0)

#  var1 var2 var3 newvar
#1   NA    1   NA      1
#2   NA   NA   NA     NA
#3   NA    0   NA      0
#4    0    0    0      0
#5    1    1    1      1
```

Comment: I've seen `NA^..` before, that's a neat trick. This can be reduced to a single line with `+(rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) * NA ^ (rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0) > 0)`

Comment: @r2evans Awesome, thanks! Somehow always forget about using `+`.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown Can you explain what NA^ is doing? I am having trouble finding documentation.

Comment: @jesse When you raise `NA` to a logical, it will return `1` if it is `FALSE` and `NA` if it is `TRUE`. So, when you multiply by the first `rowSums`, then you will get the output of `rowSums`, but will get `NA` for the row that is all `NA`, and `0` for the others that do not have a `1`.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown that is a cool trick. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

This gives your expected results:

```r
df$newvar <- 0
df$newvar[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[1:3], `%in%`, 1))] <- 1
df$newvar[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[1:3], is.na))] <- NA
df
#   var1 var2 var3 newvar
# 1   NA    1   NA      1
# 2   NA   NA   NA     NA
# 3   NA    0   NA      0
# 4    0    0    0      0
# 5    1    1    1      1
```

This defaults to 0 and only changes values with known conditions, which means that if there are any rows with `NA` and `1` (with or without `0`), it will be assigned `0`. It's not difficult to test for this, but it wasn't in your logic.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. I use ifelse() quite a bit, so I would like to understand why the "ifelse((is.na(df$var1) & is.na(df$var2) & is.na(df$var3))" seems to be applying to cases that are not applicable. It is making me doubt my understanding of how the function works.

Comment: Actually, according to the rules, row 1 should be 1. Could that be handled by replacing the "&" with "|"?

Comment: Oops, right ... I mis-typed `&`-vs-`|` in the first attempt, since fixed.